# How to open Android samples in the new Google Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

How to open Android samples in the new Google Android SDK? When creating a new android project using the latest Google Android SDK, it seems the ability to create project from existing source is now missing?

Answer (score 3):

Go to File menu in Eclipse->New->Others

[image]

so you will get open dialog like below image & select "Android Sample Project" then select api level for which you want sample project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy , but every time we can't put snap :)

Comment: thanks, not to be ironic, but why are they fragmenting the sdks now.

Comment: What do you mean by "fragmenting the sdks"?

Comment: -1 for jpeg snapshots. jpeg artifacts are horrendous. PNG is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the project from File - Import - Android - Existing Android Code Into Workspace